# UIWebView copy/paste do not keep Font face and size

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipasteboard

In a contenteditable UIWebView, when I copy then paste some text, the content is pasted with any bold or italic attributes it may have, but is font is always replaced by Times (always with size="3") whatever it was in the copied text (for example Helvetica). I filed a radar at Apple's bug website some weeks ago but got no news. Any idea to make a workaround?

Comment: facing same problem have you got solution ?